# checkbox inside gridview item template is generating a span

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have the following grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                    runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="rowEven" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="rowHead" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="row" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" data-flag="false" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

and its generating

```
 <span data-flag="false"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid_ctl02_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$myGrid$ctl02$CheckBox1" /></span>
```

I want the data flag inside the checkbox. not as an span

Comment: Handle `RowDataBound` event; find the checkbox and set it manually: `cb.Attributes["data-flag"] = "false";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible and simple workaround is to use the simple html checkbox with a `runat="server"`

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <input id="Checkbox1" runat="server" type="checkbox" data-flag="false" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Checked="false"` instead of data-flag.